# How to open image in new tab in Edge

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

In Google Chrome / Mozilla Firefox I can open an image under the mouse pointer in new tab using context menu. The menu contains "Open image in new tab" or "View Image" command for this.

How can I open an image in new tab in Edge browser?

[image: Context menu for image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right-click an image on a website while using Edge, a window appears, giving you a few different options: Ask Cortana, Save Picture As, Share Picture, Select All, and Copy.

[image: Copy screenshot]

Click Copy and open a new tab, then right-click in the address bar and choose Paste and Go in the window that appears.

[image: Paste and Go screenshot]

This will paste the image URL into the address bar or the new tab and open the image directly.  Otherwise, you can choose Paste and then press enter - the result is the same.

Comment: Any alternative to this? This no longer works, pasting after copying the image does nothing sadly.